# Gallerific .selected Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, thumbnails, selected, galleriffic

I'm having a problem with the selected element in Galleriffic. When an image is selected it is not highlighting the correct thumb, it's highlighting the previous one.

Edited to remove a soon to be dead link of the website.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
            $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '100%', 'clear' : 'both'});
            $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

            // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
            // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
            var onMouseOutOpacity = .7;
            $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li').opacityrollover({
                mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                exemptionSelector: '.selected'
            });

            // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
            var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                delay:                     2500,
                preloadAhead:              10,
                enableTopPager:            true,
                enableBottomPager:         true,
                maxPagesToShow:            7,
                imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
                controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
                captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
                loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
                renderSSControls:          false,
                renderNavControls:         false,
                playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
                pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
                prevLinkText:              '&lsaquo; Previous Photo',
                nextLinkText:              'Next Photo &rsaquo;',
                nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
                prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
                enableHistory:             false,
                autoStart:                 false,
                syncTransitions:           true,
                defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
                onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                    // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                    this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
                        .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
                        .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                },
                onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
                    this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
                },
                onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
                    this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

CSS

```
div.slideshow a.advance-link {
    display: block;
    width: 820px;
    height: 388px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
    line-height: 0px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
    text-align: center;
}
div.slideshow a.advance-link:hover, div.slideshow a.advance-link:active, div.slideshow a.advance-link:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.download {
    float: right;
}
div.image-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
div.image-desc {
}
div.navigation {
    /* The navigation style is set using jQuery so that the javascript specific styles won't be applied unless javascript is enabled. */
    text-align: left;
}
ul.thumbs {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
ul.thumbs li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
a.thumb {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.thumbs li.selected a.thumb {
    color: #0C3 
}
a.thumb:focus {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.thumbs img {
    border: none;
    display: block;
}
div.pagination {
    clear: both;
}
div.navigation div.top {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.navigation div.bottom {
    text-align: center;
}
div.pagination a, div.pagination span.current, div.pagination span.ellipsis {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
div.pagination a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.pagination span.current {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
div.pagination span.ellipsis {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an indexing problem, the  was considered like an index which was causing it to start off at the wrong place.

Solved it! :)